# I want to know specific exercises for (preferred yoga) for weight loss considering my slip disk

Tags: weight-loss, exercise, yoga, back-pain

Two years back I had fallen from a tree from a height about 2 stories straight standing on the ground. I had the x-ray at that time which showed I was ok. I ignored it and later on the pain grew to start in the back. A year before I had done an MRI scan and the reports were -

IMPRESSION: - OLD PARTIALLY DEPRESSED FRACTURE IS SEEN IN ANTEROSUPERIOR ASPECT OF L4 VERTEBRAL BODY WITH SURROUNDING FATTY MARROW CHANGES? POST-TRAUMATIC SEQUELAE

DISC DESSICATION IS SEEN AT L5-S1 WITH DIFFUSE DISC BULGE AND SMALL POSTEROCENTRAL DISC PROTUSION CAUSING MILD INDENTATION OF THECAL SAC.

I am having my treatment with a good doctor(best hospital in India) and they have suggested me few exercises and said 95% cases like this can be cured with  exercises without surgery. The problem is I am a computer science student and I have to do a lot of work sitting.  Because of that, I have gained a lot of weight. I want to do exercises for weight loss but I am afraid that it could affect my back. So, kindly anyone suggests me exercises for my weight loss and might be some diets along with so that it can go along with my back pain exercise. And I am a pure vegetarian(not even egg). I am 22 years old. Weight nearly 85 kg, height 5.7 f and BMI 29.3. And I feel pain lying on my back straight, so I just lay on side and sleep. So is there a proper posture for sleeping in this case?
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem aware of this already, but for clarity: In order to lose weight, you need a [caloric deficit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caloric_deficit).  You can achieve a caloric deficit by reducing your energy intake (consuming fewer calories) and/or increasing your energy use (using more calories).  I am not a dietician, but I recommend that you focus first on consuming fewer calories, because it is far simpler -- if you have sufficient discipline -- to achieve a caloric deficit in that way than to use more calories.

I am sorry to hear that you are dealing with such pain; it sounds rather uncomfortable.  I know of no reason not to sleep on your side.

Please consider training to strengthen your back, using [a linear progression with low-bar back squats and deadlifts](http://startingstrength.com/get-started).  If you avoid using your back, then its supporting muscles will continue to atrophy, which and your risk of further injury and pain will increase.  If you strengthen your back, then you will reduce your risk of further injury, and may find some relief from your back pain, as (anecdotally) other people have found from strength training.

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. I will keep all things in mind and do them disciplinary.